# What is the difference between red and cyan in spell check highlighting?

Tags: spell-checking, color

## My Problem

I have added the following to my `.vimrc` to enable spell checks:

```
" Spell Checking
set spelllang=en_us
set spellfile=$HOME/en.utf-8.add
set spell
```

Giving the following highlight:

[image]

Both "permalink" and "Serverless" are marked as errors, and are reachable with `]s`. However, one is cyan and the other is red, and I want to know their difference.

## What Have I Tried

- Searching for "vim spell check colors" and alike
- [RTFM](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/spell.html) and `help spell`

## My Question

**What is the meaning of the different spell check highlight colors in vim?**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If your highlighting is like mine then that would be a `SpellLocal` error.

> **SpellLocal** Word that is recognized by the spellchecker as one that is used in another region.

And...

> A word may be spelled differently in various regions.  For example,
>   English comes in (at least) these variants:
>
> **en**:         all regions
>       **en_au**:      Australia
>       **en_ca**:      Canada
>       **en_gb**:      Great Britain
>       **en_nz**:      New Zealand
>       **en_us**:      USA
>
> Words that are not used in one region but are used in another region
>   are highlighted with SpellLocal

You should be able to confirm this by running the following command which will show highlight settings for just spell check related elements.

```
:for item in ['Bad','Cap','Local','Rare']| exe "hi Spell".item| endfor
```

Here's what I see (`SpellLocal` is `Cyan`...might also show as `#008787`)

```
SpellBad       xxx term=reverse ctermbg=12 gui=undercurl guisp=Red
                   links to Error
SpellCap       xxx term=reverse ctermbg=9 gui=undercurl guisp=Blue
                   links to Error
SpellLocal     xxx term=underline ctermbg=11 gui=undercurl guisp=Cyan
                   links to Error
SpellRare      xxx term=reverse ctermbg=13 gui=undercurl guisp=Magenta
                   links to Error
```

See `:h spell-quickstart` and `:h spell-remarks`. The first one has these short descriptions of all four error types along with tag links to further help:

```
SpellBad    word not recognized         |hl-SpellBad|    
SpellCap    word not capitalised        |hl-SpellCap|    
SpellRare   rare word                   |hl-SpellRare|    
SpellLocal  wrong spelling for region   |hl-SpellLocal|
```

**Update:** Thought I'd add an example of how to see `SpellLocal` in action. The region is specified with the `'spelllang'` option. In my versions of Vim this is set to "en" by default which allows all regional spellings. However if I do `:set spelllang=en_us` and then check spelling of "green is the colour" then "colour" will be highlighted in cyan since that is not considered a correct spelling of "color" in the U.S. but is valid in other regions such as "en_gb".